# How to apply custom CIFilter to the filters property of CALayer?

Tags: cocoa, graphics, filtering, core-animation, core-image

I'm having trouble applying [custom CIFilters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html) to the [filters](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters) property of a CALayer.

```
//has no effect
layer.filters = [customFilter];
```

It's only the filters property; setting and getting all other properties works as intended.

```
//works as intended
customFilter.Image = img; 
CIImage result = customFilter.outputImage;
```

I'm working in Xamarin.Mac, but any example of this working would be much appreciated!

I'm currently testing this with all of the CIFilters in [Xamarin CIKernels test class](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/tests/monotouch-test/CoreImage/CIKernelTests.cs) and also a few of my own.

Comment: Any luck? If not, have a look at how SpriteKit uses CIFilters, in SKEffectsNodes, this might be similar to how CA does it, but I'm only guessing.

Comment: I ended up doing this in Objective-C with XCode to build a CIPlugin. I'm importing the CIPlugin during runtime. So it's not ideal, but it works for now!